# I want get SQL results in correct ascending order. How to get them?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
select age_group, sum(member_count), sum(discharge_count) 
from newtable 
group by age_group 
order by age_group;
```

It is returns these results:

| **age_group** | **member_count** | **discharge_count** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18-64 Years | 150 | 245 |
| 6-17 Years | 185 | 325 |
| 65 and Above Years | 125 | 230 |

But I want results like this instead:

| age_group | member_count | discharge_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6-17 Years | 185 | 325 |
| 18-64 Years | 150 | 245 |
| 65 and Above Years | 125 | 230 |

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images - add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Comment: You can order by a substring of the age group (before the -) cast to integer

Comment: @comodoro Can you show me a example how to do that.

Comment: See the answer by @balintd, it is probably correct

Comment: Consider splitting that column into two separate columns `start_age` and `end_age_exclusive` then you can just do `group by start_age, end_age_exclusive order by start_age, end_age_exclusive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String ordering doesn't know numbers, so what happened is that, first it compares the first letter, then the second and so on. And since the letter "6" comes after "1" in the alphabet, your results get messed up. You should extract the numbers at the beginning of the `age_group` field (with two `SPLIT_PART`s) and convert them to numeric type (with `CAST`):

```
select age_group, sum(member_count), sum(discharge_count) 
from newtable 
group by age_group 
order by CAST(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(age_group, ' ', 1), '-', 1) AS INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substring the value until the position - and sort the result,

```
select age_group, sum(member_count), sum(discharge_count) 
from newtable 
group by age_group 
order by substring(age_group, 0, position('-' in age_group) -1)::int;
```